# CRM 2011 OData relationship query tutorials

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

I am looking for some tutorials regarding oData in CRM 2011.

In particular I am looking for detailed, in-depth explanations and examples around how to use OData for querying entity relationships

Please do not point me at the CRM 2011 OData query designer.

While i agree that the tool is great, it offers no explanations as to why/how it generates queries the way they are.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to first look this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/DynamicsCRM2011/oData-endpoint).
This links were useful for me:

- [MSDN - OData System Query Options Using the REST Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461)
- [CRM 2011: Getting entity with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874562/crm-2011-getting-entity-with-javascript)
- [Using OData Retrieve in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/02/using-odata-retrieve-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx)
- [OData](http://www.odata.org/media/30002/OData.html)