# How to get the account name in dynamics cm using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to get the name of the account in dynamics crm 2011, created on a specific date.
For example, if an account is created on 4/3/2013 and the user also gives the same date then how can I get the account name using JavaScript?

Comment: With the examples in [this stack answer][1] you'll be able to build a nice query.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10650949/1528483

Comment: you should close this question and try google.  I promise it took you longer to register the account and ask the question than it would have taken to query google for "Javascript CRM 2011 retrieve" and then sift through the top 5 hits for code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered this low hanging fruit, you can do it a few different ways.  I find OData easiest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328025.aspx as Mike said in comments, you would do a retrieve. 
You can also use SOAP: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490657.aspx

Simply put in a filter for Date Created in either one and make "Name" a "Select" column.  Jorge also posted a number of good links for OData, but remember SOAP is a good alternative as well.