# How to get the value of an attribute of a entity using javascript?

Tags: javascript, attributes, entity, field, dynamics-crm-2011

For example, if I have a contact lookup field, and each contact record has many attributes, such as id, name, company, etc.  How do I get the value of, say, the company attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I can now get the value id ({55FCBC5D-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-005056A63DAF}) using Retrieve method provided by crm service, but i also need the text name of the value.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A contact lookup field is of type [`EntityReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.aspx). As such, it only contains the bare essentials needed to uniquely identify the record: its `Id` (in this case, "ContactId"), `LogicalName` (the name of the entity to which the reference belongs - in this case, "contact"), and, if you're lucky, `Name` (in this case, likely `FullName`).

So to get any additional information about the contact, you're going to have to ask the `Contact` entity for that information via a query using the `EntityReference`.`Id`. There's lots of examples of this @StackOverflow and around the web - see [CRM 2011: Getting entity with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874562/crm-2011-getting-entity-with-javascript) for a popular way here.

There is also a CodePlex project called "[CRM 2011 Lookup Preview](http://crm2011lookuppreview.codeplex.com/)" that seems to cleverly preview this sort of information on forms, but this may/may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using two queries (Retrieve method provided by crmService).