# CRM 2013 - What to do with FetchXML Query In Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamics-crm-2013, fetchxml

I currently need to retrieve a attribute that is present in a Sub-Grid, how I've done this previously is a C# Plugin with a FetchXML Query within to retrieve the attribute.

However, I want to retrieve the attribute and put its context into a field on the CRM Form. Therefore I've constructed the following in a JavaScript Web Resource

```
function getProduct()
{
var accountID = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("productid");
var AccountIDObj= accountID.getValue();

    if (AccountIDObj!=null)
    {
        AccountID= AccountIDObj[0].id;
            }

var fetch = 

"@<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' output-format='xml-platform' version='1.0'>
  <entity name = 'quotedetail'>
    <attribute name = 'productid'/>
    <attribute name = 'productdescription'/>
    <attribute name = 'priceperunit'/>
    <attribute name = 'quantity'/>
    <attribute name = 'extendedamount'/>
    <attribute name = 'quotedetailid'/>
  <link-entity name ='product' alias='bf' to='productid' from='productid'>
    <filter type = 'and'>
      <condition attribute='productnumber' value ='" + AccountID + "' operator = 'eq'/>
    </filter>
  <link-entity name='productpricelevel' alias='bg' to='productid' from ='productid'>
    <attribute name = 'amount'/>
   </link-entity>
  </link-entity>
</entity>
</fetch>"
```

The problem I now have is where to go from here, in C# I'd create a EntityCollection with the query and go from there, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876964/how-to-execute-fetchxml-in-crm-2011-using-a-crm-2011-webservice-and-javascript

Answer (score 3):

To Execute FetchXml queries on client side using Javascript, you can use below libraries

XrmServiceToolKit.js
http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Soap%20Functions

CrmFetchKit.js
https://crmfetchkit.codeplex.com/documentation

Happy coding :-)