# dynamics CRM 2011 show form in aspx page / portal

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

I wonder if there is a way to show CRM 2011 forms (like the information form of the contact entity) on an aspx page?

I want to build a customer portal (asp.net) which shows exactly the fields which are configured in the CRM itself.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like you need to keep the data within CRM and have it synced across to another server (perhaps in a DMZ) to display. Is that what your after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Put an iframe to your ASPX page and point it to the CRM form url. The URL has following format:

   [http://myhost.com/ORGNAME/main.aspx?etn={ENTITYNAME}&pagetype=entityrecord&id={ENTITYGUID}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899842/build-entity-form-url)
2. Use CRM database views (or [CRM webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876964/how-to-execute-fetchxml-in-crm-2011-using-a-crm-2011-webservice-and-javascript)) directly from your application. Configure datasource to CRM database

Downside of the first solution is that users will be probably asked for credentials (you will probably want to introduce [SSO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061.aspx)) and if the CRM is running on different domain it will be a bit difficult to ensure JavaScript communication between your page and the iframe. However, not impossible - http://easyxdm.net/wp/. Advantage is that it's pretty easy to build.

The second solution is more work but on the other hand you have everything under control.

Comment: Hi rocky, thank you for your answer. 
I was already aware of the solutions you posted. But what I try to accomplish is the following: I want to have a CRM Form or View where a Poweruser can add and remove fields. This fields should be shown in the portal as well without source code modification. I agree that 1. would be an solution for that, but as you said I would face some problems with credentials. Furthermore I would like to style the form which gets displayed on the aspx page with css. Is there a way to get the metadata of a CRM form (like: this form displayes this fields, etc.)?

Comment: I think even if there was it's not a way anyone would want to go :) There will be so much logic and overhead around those forms that you just don't want to reinvent it. If I were you I'd go with the first solution. If you dive into it it's not that hard to ensure cross-domain JS communication between two window objects - especially if one of them is an iframe. postMessage API works reliably in this case (unlike between two separate windows in ie :)). So with some effort you'd be able to style the form.

Comment: But of course you can retrieve field metadata using: 
var result = (RetrieveEntityResponse) organizationService.Execute(metadataRequest);
var metadata = result.EntityMetadata;